# Split of many Text files automatically

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I have around 3000 txt file and I want to split each file into two separate txt files based on specific phrase, for example section one and section two.

Each file looks like this :

Section one

Xxxxxxxxx
Xxxxxxxxxx
Xxxxxxxxx

Section two

Xxxxxxxxxc
Xxxxccxccc
Xxxxxxxcxx

I want to have section one and section two in two separate txt files.

Please suggest or advise me any help to perform this task. I heard about batch file but I have no idea how it works.

I'm using windows 10.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This task is doable with every common script version. But SO isn't a script writing service. You should show some effort by yourself. Googling for solutions isn't that difficult. Some hints you need to iterate through the folder, read the file line by line switching output with the next section. I vbscript/powershell there other ways with multiline RegExes.

Comment: If you can differentiate sections one and two, I would use `FOR %%a in (*.txt) do findstr "Xxxxxxxxx" "%%a">>"section1.txt"`. You can do something similar again for section 2. If not, come back with a more detailed question after your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to the previous comments. If you want to know what's going on, you should use your own efforts in reading the help for the commands used here (ie `for /?`, `findstr /?`, ...).

Despite the above, give this a try. It may need modifications involving handling `paths` or whatever your real task may be. Try your own efforts and then come back to show your progress, where are you stuck, and may be find a solution.

This script split txt files where `section two` is found and changes extension from `blabla.txt` to `blabla.one.txt` and `blabla.two.txt` each of these containing the splitted version of the original file.

The strings `Section ...` are supposed to be at the beginning of the line.

```
@echo off
for /F %%f in ('dir /B *.txt') do (
   for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%1 in (`findstr /B /N "Section" "%%f"`) do (
     if /I "%%3" EQU "two" call :split %%f, %%1
   )
)
exit/B

:split
Setlocal

set "fileone=%~1" & set "filetwo=%~1" & set/a split=%2

set "fileone=%fileone:.=.one.%" 
set "filetwo=%filetwo:.=.two.%"

copy NUL "%fileone%">NUL
copy NUL "%filetwo%">NUL

for /F "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%a in ('"type "%~1"|find /N /V """') do (
  if %%a lss %split% ( 
    echo(%%b>>"%fileone%"
  ) else ( 
    echo(%%b>>"%filetwo%" 
  )
)

Endlocal
exit/B
```

Comment: Wouldn't your batch recursivly split also the new files?

Comment: Think not, the `'dir /B *.txt'` command in `for` loop is evaluated prior to enter `for` block. But if executed twice, indeed the `for` command will find new files.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Did a rework of my batch to get all files and circumvent recursing already splittet files

```
@Echo off
For /f "Delims=" %%F in ('Dir /B/S File*.txt^|Findstr /v "_"'
) Do Set "Fout=NUL"&Set "Fin=%%~F"&For /f "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A in (
'Findstr /N /V §³$ %%F') Do Call:Sub %%B
Goto :Eof

:Sub
If %1. Equ Section. Call :SetFout %Fin% %2
>>"%Fout%" Echo:%*
Goto :Eof

:SetFout
Set "Fout=%~dpn1_%2%~x1"
Type NUL>"%Fout%"
```

Some explanations

- findstr /N is used to number the lines (required otherwise empty
  lines would be dropped)
- /V §³$ means every line NOT containing these chars, ergo all.
- for /f parses the line and cuts of the number and the remainder of the
  line is an arg to the call :sub
- if the first word is `Section` Sub :SetFout is called to build a new name Fout from Fin (In file) by appending _secondWord to it (one, two) The new file is set to NUL
- All other lines are simply copied to the current Fout